# Why is my for loop stuck on the second option?

Tags: javascript

First project - need to pull from nested arrays for a quiz but loop is stuck somehow on the second position in the array and is skipping the first. also is stuck in an infinite loop -

```
var quiz = [ 
             [ "what color is the sky?" , "blue" ],
             [ "what color are most apples?", "red" ],
             [ "what color is coffee?" , "black" ]
];

var i;
for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  if (i = 0) { 
    var ans1 = prompt(quiz[0][0]);
  } else if (i = 1) {
    var ans2 = prompt(quiz[1][0]);
  } else {
    var ans3 = prompt(quiz[2][0]);
  }
}


document.write(ans1 + ans2 + ans3);
```

My logic is that if i = 0 from the start it should run the first prompt then finish the loop adding 1 to the i variable, then run the second prompt etc.

I tried looking it up, tried a *while* loop, tried changing the last *else* to *else if (i = 2)*.

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` and `===` are comparison

Comment: Also, your last line will not work since you are declaring the variables on the scope of the `if`s. Declare them outside of the `for` loop, just like you declared `i`.

Comment: @silentw those are declared as `var` and there is no such thing as block scope for `var`s. Only ES6+ has block scope and it is for `let` and `const` variables.

Comment: To be honest this is not a very correct use of `for` loop

Comment: @MaheerAli that is absolutely true. It's basically what [this answer does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58273840/why-is-my-for-loop-stuck-on-the-second-option/#58273873) but with unnecessary steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change `if (i = 0)` to `if (i == 0)`. In Javascript and many other programming languages, `=` means assignment, but `==` means comparison. Since you're trying to compare `i` to an integer, you want the comparison operator, rather than the assignment operator.

Comment: or maybe  strict equal (===) ex if (i == 0)

Answer (score 1):

A single `=` is an assignment. You want to have a double equation to do comparison:

```js
var quiz = [ 
             [ "what color is the sky?" , "blue" ],
             [ "what color are most apples?", "red" ],
             [ "what color is coffee?" , "black" ]
];

var i;
for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  if (i == 0) { 
    var ans1 = prompt(quiz[0][0]);
  } else if (i == 1) {
    var ans2 = prompt(quiz[1][0]);
  } else {
    var ans3 = prompt(quiz[2][0]);
  }
}


document.write(ans1 + ans2 + ans3);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the `=` operator use `==` operator or better yet `===`, but again You don't need the loop or the conditions in this case.

```
var quiz = [ 
             [ "what color is the sky?" , "blue" ],
             [ "what color are most apples?", "red" ],
             [ "what color is coffee?" , "black" ]
];

var ans1 = prompt(quiz[0][0]);
var ans2 = prompt(quiz[1][0]);
var ans3 = prompt(quiz[2][0]);

document.write(ans1 + ans2 + ans3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (i = 0){
}
```

you are assigning value to variable i instead of comparing it. use "=="
 for comparing the two values in if conditon.

```
if (i == 0){
    }
```